# What is the file structure and directories of where CLEOS saves its data and user data for Ubuntu?

Tags: cleos, wallet, ubuntu, command-line

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 and was wondering where does cleos store its data? And where are user's wallet data stored when importing or creating a new eos wallet?

Answer (score 1):

In the beginning create the wallet. you can see the 'eosio-wallet' directory in /home/username.

And EOSIO program stored the data in .data folder you can see user's home folder